# Can You Create A Google Site From An Existing Google Docs Folder?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-sites

I already have an extensive Google Drive "site" containing around 100 documents, which contain links to each other. Is there anyway to transfer these files to Google Sites, to at least seed a site in Google Sites, without having to manually create a each page. This could be either via the UI or some kind of automate tool like Google Apps Script

There are a couple of questions already asking this, but they date from over 5 years ago and I'm not sure they are up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Google Apps Script doesn't support the current version of Google Sites. You could embed your Google Drive "site" by using the built-in Google Sites functions to embed content i.e. you could embed the a folder, for details see the official help article [Add Google files, video & more](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/90569?hl=en)

The only way to automate embedding content and adding links might be by using a web browser automation tool (I don't use any of this, sorry) because as mentioned previously Google Apps script doesn't support the current version of Google Sites and it hasn't an API.